# Display current category with posts and subcategories with posts in WP

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

Wordpress-Gurus,

i need some help with the wordpress query.

I am on an archive page and would like to show the corresponding posts and the subcategories with their corresponding posts as a list:

```
category1
 - post1
 - post2
 subcategory 1
  - post3
  - post4
 subcategory 2
  - post5
  - post6
```

I used the code from here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17279
This works almost, except for the direct corresponding posts of category1.

Do you have a hint?

```
<?php  
$cats = get_categories('child_of='.get_query_var('cat')); 

    foreach ($cats as $cat) :

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10, // max number of post per category
    'category__in' => array($cat->term_id)
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args); 


        echo '<h1>'.$cat->name.'</h1>';
        echo '<ul>';

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>  

        <?php /*general loop output; for instance: */ ?>

             <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>   

        <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php 

echo '</ul><hr>';
endforeach; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the parent category object first, then merge it with it's sub-categories objects

```
$main_category = get_category( get_query_var('cat') );
$cats          = get_categories( 'child_of=' . get_query_var('cat') );
$cats          = array_merge( array( $main_category ), $cats );
```